# use of if else statement in python getting runtime error

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

```
n=range(101)
if n%2==0:
     print("weird")
if range(2,6):
     print("not weird")
if range(6,21):
     print("weird")
if n>20:
     print("not weird")
else :
     print("weird")
```

Given an integer, , perform the following conditional actions:

If  is odd, print Weird
If  is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
If  is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20 , print Weird
If  is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird

Comment: Please include the error that you're getting

Comment: it's weird indeed

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `for` loop to iterate through the range generator, and you should use the `in` operator to test if `n` is in a range, and if you mean to print only upon the first matching rule for each number, you should use `elif` statements instead of `if` for the conditions that follows the first. You might also want to print the number itself so that you know which numbers are "weird" and which are "not weird":

```
for n in range(101):
    print(n, end=' ')
    if n%2==0:
         print("weird")
    elif n in range(2,6):
         print("not weird")
    elif n in range(6,21):
         print("weird")
    elif n>20:
         print("not weird")
    else:
         print("weird")
```